# Firebase query on.(child_added) execute function only after dataset is loaded

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have an Angularjs htmlfile which lists data from firebase.  Data from firebase is presented using `ng-repeat`. When the page loads, data is presented.

Trying to figure out how to trigger event when a child is added to the dataset.

[Firebase web api](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html) led to the following code:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com/test");

$scope.test= $firebaseArray(ref);  

    ref.on('child_added', function (childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {

function_to_execute();

});
```

The problem is that `function_to_execute()` is triggered on `pageload` as well as for each child added.

Is there any way to load a dataset and only trigger function when child is actually added after the dataset is loaded?

Comment: Can you add more code? Is the code you show now in a controller or somewere else?

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the $loaded promise:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com/test");

$scope.test= $firebaseArray(ref);  

ref.$loaded()
    .then(function(){
        ref.on('child_added', function (childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {
            function_to_execute();
        });
    });
```